# Uploading Laravel Project to Webuzo

Tags: laravel, vps

I've problem with Laravel Project in Webuzo. 
How to configure it from localhost to Webuzo ?
Please guide me step by step. Thanks

Comment: Is it cpanel or VPS?

Comment: it is cpanel...

Comment: Have you installed it on localhost using any Softaculous product? Import/Export would be a click away in that case.